# Why use Interfaces for domain entities?

Tags: java, interface, entity

What is the purpose of using interfaces for domain entities?

In our project, we are using interface for domain entities. Inside the interface, there are only getter and setter methods, not even any domain logic.

Is using an interface for entities like this useful? Is this good practice?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't answer why *your project* has made a particular decision. Ask your colleagues.

Comment: I'm asking in general.

Comment: In general it's a poor idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty of reasons why it's a good idea *sometimes* but it really depends on the scope of the project.

First of all: your statement "...not even any domain logic." doesn't make sense, there can't be any logic in an interface, interfaces can't have any logic, only method signatures.

The main reason why this is done is to support multiple implementations of the domain objects for different uses.

Reasons why you might want to code your domain objects to interfaces:

1. Serialization - sometimes you want to create serializable
       versions of your domain objects but don't want to mix that code up
       with the code you use for your core app. For example, you might have
       an implementation of your Person object that you just use to
       serialize to JSON for your webapp.
2. Shared API - you might want to distribute a public API version of
       your code that has different implementations of your objects, or you
       might even just want to make the interfaces available to another
       group (or client, or vendor)
3. Support for a legacy implementation - maybe you have some data in
       an old database that you need to build a connector for that involves
       a different implementation of your domain objects to pull the data
       out.
4. Testing - having interfaces for your core classes makes unit
       testing a lot easier since you can quickly stub out methods you
       don't need for testing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160855/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-mangi-why-use-interfaces-for-domain-entities).

Answer (score 3):

- I have never worked on a project where this kind of thing goes on;
- it is not typical design;
- I have never heard or read anyone claiming it is a good practice;
- I can't think of any benefit from such a design;
- I **can** think of nuisances it causes.

When you access a public instance field of a data object, you are already "programming to contract"—that's all the contract you get from a bean. The layer of accessors adds nothing, let alone another layer of interface. Java Beans are an admission of the fact that much data is just that – data – and encapsulating it behind a contract only hurts its utility. FP, probably the nicest programming paradigm in existence, got this point right.

One may ask (it's @pst, actually :), what if different entities implement different serialization strategies? What if they store data differently internally? Perhaps one is super-duper-over-clever and does lots of bit-twiddling for "performance" reasons.

Yes, we can certainly imagine **some** scenario where this is actually called for, but it goes the other way around: **first** you realize you'll be doing such a project, **then** you introduce interfaces around beans. You don't do it up front because "maybe, just maybe, this crazy requirement will come about in the middle of our project". And practice clearly shows that this almost never happens.

Also, don't forget that constructors are out of question in such a design. Enforcing a project-wide policy to write abstract factories for each and every piece of domain data—and for no definite reason—is definitely not what one could call a reasonable design choice.

Comment: @pst Which one are you interested in? The negatives hardly lend themselves to expansion :)

Comment: I am fairly interested in #5 (nuisances, as the bold drew my eye), but it would also be nice if some "common benefits of interfaces" could be ruled/reasoned-against in #4. (I mean, after all, isn't "programming to contract" a Good Thing?)

Comment: @pst When you access a public instance field of a data object, you are already "programming to contract"---that's all the contract you get from a bean. The layer of accessors adds nothing, let alone another layer of interface. Java Beans are an admission of the fact that much data is just that -- data -- and encapsulating it behind a contract only hurts its utility. FP, probably the nicest programming paradigm in existence, got it right.

Comment: What if I want to use a different bean/entity? Does not using an interface reduce coupling?

Comment: @pst A different bean with the exact same properties? How is that even possible? There are no two ways to implement the contract of "sets the `firstName` property, a `String`, to the value of the argument".

Comment: Well, why not? What if different entities implement different serialization strategies? What if they store data differently internally? Perhaps one is super-duper-over-clever and does lots of bit-twiddling for "performance" reasons.

Comment: @pst I knew you'd come up with some imaginative example :) Yes, we can certainly imagine **some** scenario where this is actually called for, but it goes the other way around: **first** you realize you'll be doing such a project, **then** you introduce interfaces around beans. You don't do it up front because "maybe, just maybe, this crazy requirement will come about in the middle of our project". And practice clearly shows that this almost never happens.

Comment: @pst Oh, and don't forget that constructors are out of question in such a design! Would you really enforce a project-wide policy to write abstract factories for each and every piece of domain data? I'm sure you wouldn't because nobody sane would.

Comment: I agree - but didn't quite realize so until I started using DI. It was then that I realized that only *some* things are [testable] Services and most other types are just an implementation detail. I think this answer would be better if moving some of the information from these comments into it.

Comment: @pst Did that. Thanks for engaging feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some developers who take the "code to an interface" advice way too far.  They think they should **always** be using an interface just in case it might come in handy one day.

Comment: Even "plain" JavaBeans are a questionable practice, especially in today's world of aspects that can advise field access. Wrapping them in another layer of abstraction is... masochistic. Masochism was a general trend in Java in the mid 2000's, to be fair, but those years are luckily behind us.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No, no. Unfortunately Java still has lot of market share - and has done little to improve the fundamental language :( While some of the Beans-Are-Everything nonsense has died, this just means it's "less painful", which is different than "non painful". (This thought was spawned from my dislike of when a company claims to have an "Environmentally Friendly" product - in most cases the correct label is "Less Environmentally Damaging".)

Comment: @pst I'm referring to much more modest goals: the recent trend trend in Java has been finding ways to reduce boilerplate, as opposed to previously, where the trend was to **increase** boilerplate.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, there isn't much I can say to that, so have a (tiny) +1 instead.